How to show that $G_p=SO(D-1)$?
Let $G=SO(D-1,1)^{‎\uparrow‎}$ be the connected Lorentz group. Let $p$ be a timelike momentum with  $p_0>0$. I want to show that $G_p=SO(D-1)$, the little group of $p=(M,0,\ldots,0)$ where $M>0$.
My try: Let $f\in G_p$. Then $f(p)=p$. This means
$$‏‎
\begin{pmatrix}
f_0^0 & f^0_1 & ‎\cdots &‎ ‎f^0_{D-1}\\‎‎
‎\vdots & ‎‎‎‎\vdots & ‎‎‎‎\ddots & ‎‎‎\vdots ‎\\‎
f^{D-1}_0 & ‎f^{D-1}_1 & ‎‎‎‎\cdots & ‎‎f^{D-1}_{D-1}‎‎
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
M \\ 0 \\ ‎\vdots ‎\\ ‎0‎
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
M \\ 0 \\ ‎\vdots ‎\\ ‎0‎
\end{pmatrix}.
$$ So $f_0^0=1$ and $f^i_0=0$ for $1\leq i\leq D-1$. How can I show that $f^0_j=0$ as well when $1\leq j\leq D-1$?

Hint: $f$ is a Lorentz matrix, so it satisfies $f^T \eta f = \eta$.
